# Enable Multi-Advertiser Ads option using Facebook ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

Using Facebook ads manager, We can create ads with property "Multi-advertiser ads".

[image]

However I could not figure out how to check if it's enabled and how to enable it while creating ads using Facebook ads API.

Comment: You ever figure this out by chance?

Comment: @TaylorFoster Nope. I haven't found any params yet